# How much need RAM of VPS for 1 store about 110 product pages and very low traffic?

Tags: server-setup, memory

I have 1 store with 110 products. Traffic is very low - max 40 visitors per day. Now i pay for a shared-hosting and all good, but reply of server is from 700 to 1200 ms.

I want rent VPS, but dont know about needed RAM for me. How much need? I want server reply to be very fast.

I have compressed js and css, optimized images, minimal images at product pages, sprites.

Comment: run Aoe_Profiler or install LestiFPC, 700/1200 ms is already way too good for you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running a 1 GB VPS (Digital Ocean) for Magento, 5k products and about a 150 visitors a day.
Just make sure your server is configured properly, caching is done where it can be done and consider setting up Redis for your session and cache.

Also don't forget about block level caching, pulling products from the database to show a top 10 most sold has impact so make sure it doesn't happen every time.

Comment: read the question, hes already has 1s speed on shared hosting, lol

Comment: @ADM What's wrong with my answer? I'm telling him it runs great on a 1 GB VPS? And I supply some additional tips for other people coming across this question and reading my answer. Please be more constructive.